# Draw ring in a grid centered on a vertex

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry

I'm trying to make a circle in a grid of frames by highlighting spaces. I did a lot of research into [Bresenham's Circle Algorithm](https://funloop.org/post/2021-03-15-bresenham-circle-drawing-algorithm.html), and many other sites about the midpoint circle algorithm. I can get the circle to highlight correctly, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to get the center to be a **vertex** instead of the center of a space. This is the code I used to draw the circle. I tried many other solutions and tweaked a lot in this, but this is what I started with.

I'm using Python 3.9.2 and tkinter.

```
import math

import tkinter as tk

class Circle():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.map_frames = []
        for i in range(15):
            self.map_frames.append([])
            self.root.rowconfigure(i, minsize=33)
            for j in range(15):
                self.root.columnconfigure(j, minsize=33)
                space = tk.Frame(master=self.root, relief='raised', borderwidth=1, bg='gray28')
                space.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='nsew')
                self.map_frames[i].append(space)

    def circle_points(self, radius):
        points = []
        x = 0
        y = -radius
        F_M = 1 - radius
        d_e = 3
        d_ne = -(2 * radius) + 5
        points.extend(self.transform_ring_points(x, y))
        while x < -y:
            if F_M <= 0:
                F_M += d_e
            else:
                F_M += d_ne
                d_ne += 2
                y += 1
            d_e += 2
            d_ne += 2
            x += 1
            points.extend(self.transform_ring_points(x, y))
        return points

    def transform_ring_points(self, x, y):
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        return [( x,  y),
                ( y,  x),
                (-x,  y),
                (-y,  x),
                ( x, -y),
                ( y, -x),
                (-x, -y),
                (-y, -x)]

    def points_to_offsets(self, points):
        pos = [0,0]
        offsets = []
        for point in points:
            dist = [point[0]-pos[0], point[1]-pos[1]]
            offsets.append(dist)
            pos = point
        return offsets

    def highlight(self, radius):
        curr_pos = [7, 7]
        points = self.circle_points(radius)
        offsets = self.points_to_offsets(points)
        
        for i in range(len(offsets)):
            curr_pos[0] += offsets[i][0]
            curr_pos[1] += offsets[i][1]
            if curr_pos[0] < 15 and curr_pos[1] < 15 and curr_pos[0] >= 0 and curr_pos[1] >= 0:
                self.map_frames[curr_pos[1]][curr_pos[0]].config(bg='SpringGreen3')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    circ = Circle(window)
    circ.highlight(3)
    window.mainloop()
```

I know the code is a little long, but it is best [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that fully explains the issue.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to draw the circle with center point at `curr_pos`?

Comment: What would the circle look like if it was drawn the way you want?

Comment: I would like the radius to be calculated on a vertex. Technically, that point would be (7.5, 7.5), but every time I attempt to implement a variation on this, it either draws a square or an incorrect circle.

Comment: The best way I can explain how it would look is from one of the references I used. This [post](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/circle-drawing/) shows a great example in the last figure in the 5th section for Aesthetics. Unfortunately, it doesn't explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the issue using another method. Instead of following the path in the midpoint circle algorithm, I found the left and right sides of the circle and transformed the points into the other quadrants. Due to the use of rounding, I also had to correct the values by 1 when applicable.

```
def circle_points(self, radius):
    points = []
    y = 1
    x = radius

    while x > y:
        dy = y - 0.5
        dx = math.sqrt(radius*radius - dy*dy)
        left = math.ceil(0.5 - dx)
        right = math.floor(0.5 + dx)
        points.extend(self.transform_no_fill(left, y))
        points.extend(self.transform_no_fill(right, y))
        y += 1

    return points

def transform_no_fill(self, x, y):
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    return [
        (  x,   y),
        (1-y,   x),
        (1-x, 1-y),
        (  y, 1-x)
    ]
```

Here is the full code:

```
import math

import tkinter as tk

class Circle():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.map_frames = []
        for i in range(14):
            self.map_frames.append([])
            self.root.rowconfigure(i, minsize=33)
            for j in range(14):
                self.root.columnconfigure(j, minsize=33)
                space = tk.Frame(master=self.root, relief='raised', borderwidth=1, bg='gray28')
                space.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='nsew')
                self.map_frames[i].append(space)

    def circle_points(self, radius):
        points = []
        y = 1
        x = radius

        while x > y:
            dy = y - 0.5
            dx = math.sqrt(radius*radius - dy*dy)
            left = math.ceil(0.5 - dx)
            right = math.floor(0.5 + dx)
            points.extend(self.transform_no_fill(left, y))
            points.extend(self.transform_no_fill(right, y))
            y += 1

        return points

    def transform_no_fill(self, x, y):
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        return [
            (  x,   y),
            (1-y,   x),
            (1-x, 1-y),
            (  y, 1-x)
        ]

    def points_to_offsets(self, points):
        pos = [0,0]
        offsets = []
        for point in points:
            dist = [point[0]-pos[0], point[1]-pos[1]]
            offsets.append(dist)
            pos = point
        return offsets

    def highlight(self, radius):
        curr_pos = [6, 6]
        points = self.circle_points(radius)
        offsets = self.points_to_offsets(points)
        
        for i in range(len(offsets)):
            curr_pos[0] += offsets[i][0]
            curr_pos[1] += offsets[i][1]
            if curr_pos[0] < 15 and curr_pos[1] < 15 and curr_pos[0] >= 0 and curr_pos[1] >= 0:
                self.map_frames[curr_pos[1]][curr_pos[0]].config(bg='SpringGreen3')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    circ = Circle(window)
    circ.highlight(4)
    window.mainloop()
```